# How to deal with variables going out of scope in nested roles?

Tags: ansible

I have been given a role "openldap_vpn" that runs a docker container running wireguard-go.
My goal is to translate that to install a systemd service that performs a DNS lookup and starts podman. A second (dependent) service runs inside the container to do the actual forwarding through the tunnel.

`openldap_vpn` has a var called `server` and includes `podman_wireguard_forwarder` (used on both sides) which in turn includes `podman_user_service`, which in turn includes `create-service` - where `server` is still required for the resolution of other template variables. But it is somehow dropped on the way down. It's still present in `podman_user_service` when checking with `debug`.

In the `vars` folder of `openldap`, there is a dict called `server`:

```
server:
  public_key: MFrZG5hi29Yp0U/p2RauSUUH8EAiE2wBcqX3p8jkG28=
  inside_ip: whatever
  host: whatever
  port: whatever
```

`openldap_vpn` includes `podman_wireguard_forwarder` and passes various other variables that depend on `server`:

```
---
- include_role: name=podman_wireguard_forwarder
  vars:
    name: openldap_vpn
    # needs private key
    listen_port: "{{ server.port }}"
    peers:
    - allowed_ips:
      - "{{ server.inside_ip }}/32"
      endpoint: ENDPOINT_IP
      public_key: "{{ server.public_key }}"
    forward_port: 3389
    forward_dst:
      host: "{{ server.inside_ip }}"
      port: 3389
    config_prepare_command: "ip=\"$(getent hosts '{{ server.host }}' | awk '{ print $1 }')\" ; sed -E \"s/ENDPOINT_IP/$ip/\""
```

`podman_wireguard_forwarder` still has the variable (when checking with `debug`) and uses it to create config files.

```
- name: install wireguard config template
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ user }}"
  template:
    src: wireguard_config
    dest: "{{ wg_config }}.template"

- include_role: name=podman_user_service
  vars:
    service_name: "{{ service_name_vpn }}"
    params: |-
      --network "{{ podman_network }}" \
      --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
      -v /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun \
      -v "{{ wg_config }}:/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf"
    image: docker.io/masipcat/wireguard-go:latest
    start_pre: "/bin/sh -c '{{ config_prepare_command }}' < '{{ wg_config}}.template' > '{{ wg_config }}'"
```

`podman_user_service` can still access the variable when checking with `debug`:

```
- debug:
    msg: "still works: {{ server }}"

- name: "update podman image {{ image }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ user }}"
  shell: podman image pull "{{ image }}"
  when: not image | regex_search('^localhost/')

- include_role: name=create-service
```

Now, `create-service` fails when executing the configuration template:

```
  - name: "copy {{ service_name }} service file"
    become: yes
    become_user: "{{ user if scope == 'user' else omit }}"
    template:
      src: service
      dest: "\
          {{ '/home/' + user + '/.config/systemd/user' if scope == 'user' else '/etc/systemd/system' }}\
          /{{ service_name }}.service"
```

With the following message:

```
ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: [{'allowed_ips': ['{{ server.inside_ip }}/32'], 'endpoint': 'ENDPOINT_IP', 'public_key': '{{ server.public_key }}'}]: 'server' is undefined. 'server' is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using `server` as a name for a variable seems to itch Ansible ever so slightly despite no other roles using the name.

After changing the name to `openldap_server`, the template executes correctly in the nested role.